# how do I set a value for a ShapeKey in Blender Python?

Tags: python, 3d, blender, bpython, bpy

I've managed to insert Shape Keys from Python using:

```
ob = Scene.GetCurrent().object.active;
if(ob.activeShape == 0):
   ob.insertShapeKey()
   ob.insertShapeKey()
```

Now how do I change a key value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I did it:

```
#get the key
k = ob.getData().getKey()
#create a new Ipo
ni = Ipo.New('Key','ni')
#if there check if there already a key by that name, otherwise add key
if(k.ipo['Key 1'] == None):   k.ipo.addCurve('Key 1')
#add a point to the 'Key 1' ipo curve
k.ipo['Key 1'].append(BezTriple.New(6.0,0.8,0.1))
```

And that's about it. 
The first ShapeKey inserted creates 'Basis', then keys are added,
'Key 1' is the default name